# Search a keyword "royal enfield" from database using preg_match() php function but didn't works no error even i'm getting

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print some keyword i.e "Royal enfield" from database using php function preg_match() but i'm unable to do that how can i approad to search that keyword which is "Royal enfield" from my databse using preg_match() fucntion.

```
<?php

$url='localhost';
$username='readonly';
$password='';
$db_name = 'impact';
$conn=mysqli_connect($url,$username,$password,"impact");
if(!$conn){
 die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
}

//import.php
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($_POST);die();
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$csvname = $_POST['csv_file'];


$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("idata.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        // echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            $query = "SELECT * FROM wm_article WHERE id = '".$data[$c]."'";
            $exec = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $details = mysqli_fetch_array($exec);
            $description = $details['title'] ." ".$details['description'];
             echo $description ;

             $pattern = "/royal enfield/" ;

             if (preg_match($pattern, $keyword)) {
                 echo $description ;
             }
           else {
               echo "No match found!" ;
           }


        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: This code doesn't do what you're requesting... looking at it, it opens a CSV, loops through it line-by-line and performs an SQL `SELECT` query based on some data from that CSV... then you're randomly comparing the pattern `/royal enfield/` to a keyword posted from a form (probably) which has nothing to do with your query. If you're attempting to search for something in the database, then you want to do that in your `SELECT` query (either with `LIKE`, `REGEXP` or better yet a FULL TEXT search index) - otherwise you'd have to pull **everything** then look for matches afterwards.

Comment: first i import csv to match data and then after matching data i need to pull match words from it , so i guess my code is correct only pregmatch() is wrong i appreciate if you will give a solution rather then devoting my question

Comment: I'm trying to determine *exactly* what it is you're trying to do, because if you're just trying to search for "royal enfield" in the database, which the question implies, it seems like you're going about it the wrong way - however, it looks like, from the code, that's **not** what you're trying to do... so what are you trying to do *exactly*? Where does the CSV come into it? Or if you're trying to find "royal enfield" in the CSV, where does the database come into it? Or are you trying for find matches to the keyword that are in both the database and CSV?

Comment: I'm explaining mate i made a page where i upload a csv manually which contain some ids that ids matched with database and print matching data  i want to search some keywords from that matching data. Like royal Enfield.

Comment: I might not be quite getting it, but do you not just want something like: `preg_match('/' . preg_quote($keyword) . '/i', $details['description']) { ... }`

Comment: `mysql_error()` is not a function. You are looking for `mysqli_connect_error()`

Comment: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)